# Find the words in a string either side of a given word

Tags: regex, bash, perl, scripting

I have the following Perl script

```
$filters = "SELECT lead_id, status, user, title, first_name, last_name, city, phone_number FROM vicidial_list , vicidial_lists WHERE vicidial_list.list_id = vicidial_lists.list_id";
$stmtA   = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'asterisk' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vicidial_list'";
$sthA    = $dbhA->prepare( $stmtA ) or die "preparing: ", $dbhA->errstr;

$sthA->execute or die "executing: $stmtA ", $dbhA->errstr;

$counter = 0;
$columns = ();

while ( my @row = $sthA->fetchrow_array ) {

    # GET the name columns by pos
    $column = "@row[0] \n";

    # Check if exists the name columns
    if ( index( $filters, @row[$counter] ) > -1 ) {

        $find    = @row[$counter];
        $replace = "vicidial_list." . @row[$counter];

        # Replace the name column
        $filters =~ s/$find/$replace/g;

    }
}

print $filters . "\n\n";

#Close connection
$sthA->finish();
```

In the part that has a comment `# Check if exists the name columns` I want to know what have after and before some string.

For example, with `MY NAME IS CRISTOPHER` if I select `NAME` then it should return that it is preceded by `MY` and followed by `IS`.

Comment: How is this a question about bash?

Comment: (BTW -- it's a little hard to tell what you're asking. If you could build a [mcve] that simplified as much as possible, it would be easier to understand if we hard something with input, existing output, desired output, and code that didn't include any unrelated/irrelevant factors -- for instance, if the question isn't *about* SQL, it would be ideal to not have SQL be an element of the code).

Comment: The script is in Perl but can be in Bash too.

Comment: Thanks, I goint to try write a best example. I don't know a good english. Thanks Charles.

Comment: With GNU grep: `echo "MY NAME IS CRISTOPHER" | grep -Eo '[^ ]* NAME [^ ]*'`?

Comment: One way, simplest case: `my ($before, $after) = $string =~ /(\w+)\s+$name\s+(\w+)/;`  where `$name` has `NAME` or whatever you need to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about finding a pattern in a string, in perl, so one answer could be with regular expressions:

```
my $string='MY NAME IS';
my $pattern='NAME';
if ($string =~ /$pattern/) {
    print "Before: $`\n";
    print "After: $'\n";
}
```

See also the whole list of special [RE variables](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=353259).